# Rails 5: Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I just upgraded our Rails app from `4.2.5` to `5.0.1`

The rails server boots up fine but when I try to load a page I'm now getting the error:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'
```

When I run `bundle` I can see

```
Using jquery-rails 4.2.2
Using jquery-ui-rails 6.0.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the file paths have changed. According to the [gem readme](https://github.com/jquery-ui-rails/jquery-ui-rails#warning):

> Warning:
>
> Due to directory structure changes between jQuery UI 1.10, 1.11, and 1.12, if you use version is lower than 6.0, you will have to use a different naming for the files to require, please check following links for more information: for 5.0 users, for 4.2 users.

Comment: Changes to: //= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? Seems like you're running > 6.0 so the directory changes in the readme don't seem applicable. I ask because I'm having the same issues and running similar gem versions as you. jquery-rails (4.3.1, 4.2.1, 4.0.5)
jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1, 5.0.5)

Answer (score 6):

change the line in application.js

from

```
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
```

to

```
 //= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
```

Comment: This did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My case was exceptionally weird. When I set up my old legacy app in Ubuntu 20 it worked fine until I rebooted my laptop. After that it displayed the error under question. I checked that I use correct RVM gemset with correct ruby version, gems were bundled as they should have.

When I changed the

```
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
```

to

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
```

this line passed and worked fine, but next ones starting causing problems.

Eventually I had to change all the following lines:

```
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/autocomplete
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/datepicker
//= require jquery-ui/widgets/droppable
```

**EXCEPT THIS:**
`//= require jquery-ui/effect` and I have no idea why this single line works while others don't :/